# array of radio - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, radio-button

i have the code below and it shows a list of radio buttons
My question is how i can make a list of buttons, the equivalent for this in an array mode (jquery)

```
  <input type="radio" name="name1" value="450" /> 450€<br />
  <input type="radio" name="name2" value="500" /> 500€<br />
  <input type="radio" name="name3" value="550" /> 550€<br />
  <input type="radio" name="name4" value="600" /> 600€<br />
  <input type="radio" name="name5" value="650" /> 650€<br />
  <input type="radio" name="name6" value="700" /> 700€<br />
```

this simple make an array without change anything. And another question, how i will can access the values when i will have this in an array mode?

thanks

Comment: what's the deal with the unmatched `</div>` tag within your `<li>` element?

Comment: "without change nothing", or "without changing anything"? I'm not merely picking at your English; the two are polarly opposite.

Comment: Are you trying to clone exactly the same inputs and append them to another element?

Comment: please see my comment response -@x10

Comment: no, no. It can be independent values. I just post the unique way that i know to make an array of elements in jquery, but obviously for this case is not applicable. Ignore my code, i just want to avoid twenty lines where the unique change is the value (400,450,500,550,600 and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another jQuery solution:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NnxE3/)**

```
<ul>
    <li id="lista"></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var start = 450;
    for (var x=0; x<=20; x++) {
        var item = document.createElement('input');
            $(item).attr('type', 'radio');
            $(item).attr('id', 'price'+x+1);    // numbered starting from 1
            $(item).attr('name', 'price');
            $(item).attr('value', start + (x * 50));
        var label = document.createElement('label');
            $(label).attr('for', 'price'+x+1);  // numbered starting from 1
            $(label).html(start + (x * 50) + '€');
        $('#lista').append(item);
        $('#lista').append(label);
        $('#lista').append('<br>');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create 20 inputs and increment value and text by 50

```
var count = 20;
var increment = 50;

for (y = 0; y < count; y++) {
    var inp = '<input type="radio" name="name1" value="' + increment + '" /> ' + increment + '<br />';
    $(inp).appendTo('#lista');
    increment = increment + 50;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/fxmmN/1/

Comment: I had a typo in the name attribute, make sure you checking the updated link at http://jsfiddle.net/fxmmN/1/

Comment: you may want to use `var y = 0` to avoid polluting the globals.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will guide you in the right direction! I built a simple function create as many radios as you specify and increment the value by 50. Try modifying this a little to get to your desired solution!

```
function populateRadios(){
  var i = 0,
      numberOfRadios = 3,
      baseNumber = 0;
    for(i; i<numberOfRadios; i++){
        var aRadio = document.createElement('input');
        aRadio.type = 'radio'
        aRadio.name = 'radio1';
        aRadio.id = 'radio' + i;
        baseNumber += 50;
        aRadio.value = baseNumber

       $('#theForm').append(aRadio)
    } 
}
populateRadios()
```